# Recovering Ubuntu 14.04 after installing Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

How can I reuse/access my Ubuntu 14.04 Operating System(OS) to get my important files.

My Hard disk drive(HDD) is partitioned into two.I had previously installed both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 (on each partition) on my IBM T60 Thinkpad. The Boot-screen that always showed up was that of Ubuntu and I would select either "Ubuntu" or "Windows 7" from there. They(OS) were working very well except Windows 7 had viruses so I had to re-install it. I managed to re-install it but now on booting, it doesn't display any Boot-screen but that of windows 7.

On the hard disk drive(HDD) the partition for Ubuntu is still present.And it occupies all the partition though windows 7 can't show it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

When you re-installed windows, the grub files were deleted. You need to re-install grub.

You can read it here: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows?lq=1)

Please upvote my answer if it helped